# iteration in a data frame

Tags: dataframe

I have two columns information. The right column information are linked with the left column. While the value in left column is same, the information in right column will continually been filled in (without repeat the same value in left column) until the value on left column become different. For example, the name will be filled in column N and detailed information for same person will be filled in column O until the name changed. When the name changed, the new name will be entered in column N and detailed information will be filled in column N.

[image: example]

Comment: "Data frame" ... SQL? R? Pandas? Please show the relevant code, not a screenshot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding append, I think this link is really helpful https://py.checkio.org/mission/group-equal-consecutive/publications/kalauroma7997/python-3/first/share/021c121d8b6d5ab679f361b589fa7351/

```
pd.read_excel('test_file')
num_row = len(test_file['NAME'])
new_row = 0

group_infor=[]
new_row=0
pyautogui.click(x, y) #this x, y is the start place you want to add your first NAME
time.sleep(0.8)
for ind in range(1, num_row):
    if test_for_reorder['NAME'][ind-1]!=test_file['NAME'][ind]:
        use_append=test_file['INFORMATION'][new_row:ind]
        pyautogui.typewrite(test_file['NAME'][ind-1])
        time.sleep(0.8)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(0.8)
        for vn_nbr in use_append:           
            pyautogui.typewrite(INFORMATION)
            time.sleep(0.8)
            pyautogui.press('down')
            time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.press('left')
        time.sleep(0.8)
```